# Java Exception in Counting number of occurrences of character in a string

Tags: java, string, exception, character

I am a java beginner and want to do some logic stuffs. I have started with a simple program (i.e) to find the total number of occurrences of a character in a string. But i ended up with this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 52
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
```

And i used the following code

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String myStr = "sofdaasdasdaofsdwerwtytuoftyutyusdfsdfsdcsadaswdeasd";
        // Counting number of occurences of 'of' in myStr
        int counter = 0;
        int totalLength = myStr.length();
        char char1;
        char char2;
        // To find of
        String myVal = "of";
        String cmpVal1;
        String cmpVal2;
        String cmpValStr;
        for (int i = 0; i < totalLength; i++) {
            char1 = myStr.charAt(i);
            cmpVal1 = Character.toString(char1);
            char2 = myStr.charAt(i + 1);
            cmpVal2 = Character.toString(char2);
            cmpValStr = cmpVal1 + cmpVal2;
            if (cmpValStr == myVal) {
                counter++;
            }

        }
        System.out.print(counter);
    }

}
```

Comment: I believe culprit is  `char2 = myStr.charAt(i + 1);` and to compare Strings use [`String.equals()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#equals(java.lang.Object))

Comment: I don't understand, which character are you searching for? Or, are you searching for the String "of" within the string "sofdaasdasdaofsdwerwtytuoftyutyusdfsdfsdcsadaswdeasd"?

Comment: sorry. It was my mistake i have not went through my code properly before posting my question here. Now i understood, thanks to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < totalLength-1; i++) {
    //additional code..
    if (cmpValStr.equals(myVal)) {
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Your 'for' loop should look like that. Make sure you subtract 1 from the String's length due to your increment of char2.

Also, when comparing the two strings use the .equals()

**Although, if you're interested, this is how I would have done it:**

```
String myStr = "sofdaasdasdaofsdwerwtytuoftyutyusdfsdfsdcsadaswdeasd";
int counter=0;
for(int i=0;i<myStr.length()-1;i++){
    if(myStr.subSequence(i, i+2).toString().contains("of"))
    {
        counter++;
    }
}
System.out.print(counter);
```

Answer (score 0):

i+1; here is the problem.

```
 char2 = myStr.charAt(i + 1);

 cmpValStr = cmpVal1 + cmpVal2;  // use equals for String.

 for (int i = 0; i < totalLength - 1; i++) // Not i< totalLength
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

this is your problem:

```
char2 = myStr.charAt(i + 1);
```

you go out of bounds with this on the last char.

try doing:

for (int i = 0; i < totalLength-1; i++)